# What battery to use for a MG996R High Torque Servo?

Tags: power-supply, batteries, servo

This servo’s operating voltage is 4.8v - 7.2v. The running current is 6v @ 500mA - 900mA, and the stall current is 2.5A @ 6v.

Now, I plan on using this servo 24/7 on my door lock ( this might be a stupid idea, but I am trying to experiment).

What are good battery sources ( or battery capacity to expect to buy ) to use if I want to power this for as long as I can, and on average how often should I expect to change or recharge its battery?

Comment: Impossible to tell without static & dynamic servo load thus current then Wh energy./Amps=hours

Comment: And duty cycle: how many times a day will it be used? How long does it take to change position? Does it draw current if stalled or at end of travel?

Comment: I'll say the servo will be used to turn 90 degrees 16x daily. It takes 1000ms to turn the servo 90 degrees

Comment: "...if I want to power this for **as long as I can**" - http://www.amerescosolar.com/6cs25p-6-volt-5000-series-1156-amphour-100-hr-rate-deep-cycle-flooded-battery